# ASP.NET button server side logic not being executed after javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, validation

I am having a great deal of trouble with client side validation using JavaScript and jQuery.

I have 2 user controls (`.ascx`) on a page (`.aspx`) each with its own button defined as follows

```
Page
    user control 1
        textbox 1
        textbox 2
        Button 1
    user control 2
        textbox 3
        textbox 4
        Button 2
```

Both button 1 and button 2 have the same CSS class.
I also have a JavaScript script that is referenced by the page.

Using jQuery I can accurately select the buttons and bind click events to them as follows:

```
$('.buttonCssClass').click(function() {
    // If the user control fields are not valid then do nothing

    if (typeof (Page_IsValid) == 'undefined' || Page_IsValid) {
        return false;
    }

    // If the user control fields are valid then 
    // disable the button and replace the CSS class and add an image (progress spindle)
    // until the processing is over - this is to prevent the user from clicking multiple              
    // times for long running and async processes.
});
```

When I click on button 1 I only want to check the fields in that user control for validity - not the all the fields in the page. Right now, all fields in all controls on the page are checked for validity - this means that my JavaScript function always returns `false`.

Could someone help me out with this?

Comment: @Tim - thanks for the edit. only my second question on this site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Specify [`ValidationGroups`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227424.aspx) so that not the whole page is validated. That works also on clientside:

```
if(typeof(Page_ClientValidate) == 'function')
    return Page_ClientValidate("MyValidationGroup");
```

- [ASP.NET Validation in Depth(clientside)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479045.aspx#aspplusvalid_clientside)

Comment: That's just GR8! Thank you very much!

Comment: the above technique works gr8 if I hard code the validation group - but I need to get it programatically from jquery or javascript. I've tried $(this).attr("ValidationGroup").nodeValue but the ValidationGroup attribute is not rendered in html. Do you have any ideas about this. thanks.

Comment: You could insert the correct ValidationGroup from codebehind(f.e. in Page_Load of your UserControls): `Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Page.GetType, "initValidationGroup", "var myValidationGroup='Control1ValGroup';", True)`. Then you can use this js-variable from your validation function.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can check in the click function which control raise the event.

Comment: mmm - thank you for your input -> pls could you provide some sample code to do this?

Comment: $('.buttonCssClass').click(function(event) {
    var tagId = event.target.id;
}